# How to prevent or reduce redirects after Login

Tags: administration, configuration

If a user enters the url `https://<our-qa-stage>.sandbox.lightning.force.com` several redirects occur.

#### Actual

The actual noticeable behaviour is this

1. user opens `https://<our-qa-stage>.sandbox.lightning.force.com` and logs in
2. redirect to `https://<our-qa-stage>.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/home/home.jsp`
3. redirect to `https://<our-qa-stage>.sandbox.lightning.force.com/one/one.app`
4. redirect to `https://<our-qa-stage>.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning`
5. redirect to `https://<our-qa-stage>.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/page/home`

In an [har file](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/har/info) i found 14 redirects for the reqular expression `redirectURL": "[^"]` which stands for find all redirectURL matches that are not empty like this `redirectURL": ""`

#### Desired / Expected

If only 1 redirect would occur

1. user opens `https://<our-qa-stage>.sandbox.lightning.force.com` and logs in
2. redirect to `https://<our-qa-stage>.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/page/home`

#### Questions

1. Is there an option to avoid / reduce redirects?
2. optional: Have you encountered any problems for automated tests with playwright caused by redirects?

Comment: Question 1: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Question 2 is your actual question.

Comment: In my case [it is not an xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256420/201728); there is a [benefit of lesser redirects](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/performance/redirects/). But my current impression with salesforce is that everybody must be prepared to "enjoy" / endure the user experience.

Comment: Agree about the benefit of fewer redirects but this doesn't change the nature of our comment. Based on your question 2, allegedly the problem you're trying to solve is testing the web UI and automation thereof.  Reducing the redirects (as enjoyable as it might be) is a solution-space crutch, the Y in XY. If you have an issue with, say, web UI  accessibility or performance where excessive redirects might be a root cause, you should edit you question.